# Regex match when spaces are removed, how to delete the matched chars from the original string with spaces?

Tags: python, regex, string

(disclaimer: this is my first stackoverflow question so forgive me in advance if I'm not too clear)

**Expected results:**

My task is to find company legal identifiers in a string representing a company name, then separate them from it and save them in a separate string. 
The company names have already been cleaned so that they only contain alphanumeric lowercase characters.

Example:

```
company_1 = 'uber wien abcd gmbh'
company_2 = 'uber wien abcd g m b h'
company_3 = 'uber wien abcd ges mbh'
```

should result in

```
company_1_name = 'uber wien abcd'
company_1_legal = 'gmbh'
company_2_name = 'uber wien abcd'
company_2_legal = 'gmbh'
company_3_name = 'uber wien abcd'
company_3_legal = 'gesmbh'
```

**Where I am right now:**

I load the list of all company ids up from a csv file. Austria provides a good example. Two legal ids are:

```
gmbh
gesmbh
```

I use a regex expression that tells me **IF** the company name contains the legal identifier. However, this regex removes *all* spaces from the string in order to identify the legal id.

```
company_1_nospace = 'uberwienabcdgmbh'
company_2_nospace = 'uberwienabcdgmbh'
company_3_nospace = 'uberwienabcdgesmbh'
```

since I look for the regex in the string without spaces, I am able to see that all three companies have legal ids inside their name.

**Where I am stuck:**

I can say whether there is a legal id in `company_1`, `company_2`, and `company_3` but I can only remove it from `company_1`.
In fact, I cannot remove `g m b h` because it does not match, but I can say that it is a legal id. The only way I could remove it is to also remove spaces in the rest of the company name, which I dont want to do (it would only be a last resort option)

Even if I were to insert spaces into `gmbh` to match it with `g m b h`, I would then not pick up `ges mbh` or `ges m b h`.
(Note that the same thing happens for other countries)

**My code:**

```
import re
re_code = re.compile('^gmbh|gmbh$|^gesmbh|gesmbh$')
comp_id_re = re_code.search(re.sub('\s+', '', company_name))
if comp_id_re:
    company_id = comp_id_re.group()
    company_name = re.sub(re_code, '', company_name).strip()
else:
    company_id = ''
```

Is there a way for python to *understand* which characters to remove from the original string? 
Or would it just be easier if somehow (that's another problem) I find all possible alternatives for legal id spacing? ie from `gmbh` I create `g mbh`, `gm bh`, `gmb h`, `g m bh`, etc... and use that for matching/extraction?

I hope I have been clear enough with my explanation. Thinking about a title for this was rather difficult.

**UPDATE 1:** company ids are usually at the end of the company name string. They can occasionally be at the beginning in some countries.

**UPDATE 2:** I think this takes care of the company ids inside the company name. It works for legal ids at the end of the company name, but it does not work for company ids at the beginning

```
legal_regex = '^ltd|ltd$|^gmbh|gmbh$|^gesmbh|gesmbh$'
def foo(name, legal_regex):
    #compile regex that matches company ids at beginning/end of string
    re_code = re.compile(legal_regex)
    #remove spaces
    name_stream = name.replace(' ','')
    #find regex matches for legal ids
    comp_id_re = re_code.search(name_stream)
    #save company_id, remove it from string
    if comp_id_re:
        company_id = comp_id_re.group()
        name_stream = re.sub(re_code, '', name_stream).strip()
    else:
        company_id = ''
    #restore spaced string (only works if id is at the end)
    name_stream_it = iter(name_stream)
    company_name = ''.join(next(name_stream_it) if e != ' ' else ' ' for e in name)
       return (company_name, company_id)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I got to an acceptable solution. I used part of my original code, part of the code by @Abhijit and the main idea behind @wei2912 's code.
Thank you all

Here is the code I am going to use:

```
legal_ids = '^ltd|ltd$|^gmbh|gmbh$|^gesmbh|gesmbh$'

def foo(name, legal_ids):
    #initialize re (company id at beginning or end of string)
    re_code = re.compile(legal_ids)
    #remove spaces from name
    name_stream = name.replace(' ','')
    #search for matches
    comp_id_re = re_code.search(name_stream)
    if comp_id_re:
        #match was found, extract the matching company id
        company_id = comp_id_re.group()
        #remove the id from the string without spaces
        name_stream = re.sub(re_code, '', name_stream).strip()
        if comp_id_re.start()>0:
            #the legal id was NOT at the beginning of the string, proceed normally
            name_stream_it = iter(name_stream)
            final_name = ''.join(next(name_stream_it) if e != ' ' else ' ' for e in name)
        else:
            #the legal id was at the beginning of the string, so do the same as above, but with the reversed strings
            name_stream_it = iter(name_stream[::-1])
            final_name = ''.join(next(name_stream_it) if e != ' ' else ' ' for e in name[::-1])
            #reverse the string to get it back to normal
            final_name = final_name[::-1]
    else:
        company_id = ''
        final_name = name
    return (final_name.strip(), company_id)
```

Answer (score 1):

Non-Regex solution would be easier here, and this is how, I would do it

```
legal_ids = """gmbh
gesmbh"""
def foo(name, legal_ids):
    #Remove all spaces from the string
    name_stream = name.replace(' ','')
    #Now iterate through the legal_ids
    for id in legal_ids:
            #Remove the legal ID's from the string
        name_stream = name_stream.replace(id, '')
    #Now Create an iterator of the modified string
    name_stream_it = iter(name_stream)
    #Fill in the missing/removed spaces
    return ''.join(next(name_stream_it) if e != ' ' else ' ' for e in name)

foo(company_1, legal_ids.splitlines())
'uber wien abcd '
foo(company_2, legal_ids.splitlines())
'uber wien abcd '
foo(company_3, legal_ids.splitlines())
'uber wien abcd '
```

Comment: This is good, but not 100%. In fact `foo` removes company legal ids from the whole string, regardless of where it finds the company id. so say a company is called `smelt division` in UK, this would return `sme ivision` `ltd`, I guess.
EDIT: actually, it returns `smeiv ision`

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code I came up with:

```
company_1 = 'uber wien abcd gmbh'
company_2 = 'uber wien abcd g m b h'
company_3 = 'uber wien abcd ges mbh'
legalids = ["gmbh", "gesmbh"]

def info(company, legalids):
    for legalid in legalids:
        found = []

        last_pos = len(company)-1
        pos = len(legalid)-1
        while True:
            if len(legalid) == len(found):
                newfound = found
                newfound.reverse()
                if legalid == ''.join(newfound):
                    return [company[:last_pos+1].strip(' '), legalid]
                else:
                    break

            if company[last_pos] == ' ':
                last_pos -= 1
                continue
            elif company[last_pos] == legalid[pos]:
                found.append(company[last_pos])
                pos -= 1
            else:
                break
            last_pos -= 1
    return

print(info(company_1, legalids))
print(info(company_2, legalids))
print(info(company_3, legalids))
```

Output:

```
['uber wien abcd', 'gmbh']
['uber wien abcd', 'gmbh']
['uber wien abcd', 'gesmbh']
```

Comment: I'm not sure why, but
`company_1 = 'uber wien abcd ltd'`
`legalids = ["ltd", "gmbh", "gesmbh", "spa"]`
results in `None`
(`company_2 = 'uber wien abcd ges mbh spa'` instead correctly identifies `spa` as legal id)
Also, I guess it would not be too difficult to make it go forward instead of backwards in order for it to see the legal ids at the beginning of the strings

Comment: @mkin figured out the problem: when the found array is of the same length, the letter "d" is detected again and added to the found array, thus causing it to fail.